# Text filling the button

Tags: android, button, text, scale

Is there any way (preferably easy one..) to make text inside of a button fill it completely? I've searched for xml options to do that but haven't found anything, buttons api doesnt look promising either.

Comment: Can you post an image of what exactly you want?

Comment: What do you mean? Just some letter X that completely fills the button, like this if it were a button https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTD8cvMbkGEPiMnDAwMnC9VC4_W7Wag7jKoosHV-jzX60mFjV2m